# ms word 2013- corruption and margins set outside print area

Tags: microsoft-word, margins

If i have an ms word 2013 document with background rectangle shape of gradient color covering the whole page (so the margins are set outside the printable area) and get the error "one or more marins are set outside of the printable area" and don't fix it, could it eventually cause corruption of the file and/or printing variances in spacing and object location?

I have read on word.mvps.org that corrupt printer drivers can corrupt a word doc. How can I keep this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

The printer driver cannot corrupt the Word file, as it only *reads* it.

It can produce corrupt output though - meaning the print result looks wrong. The original Word file will still be fine.